# Show hide divs using animate function

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

Hello I am trying to animate few divs from the bottom of a page, when user clicks on certain links.

E.g is a link that says 'About' is clicked on, I need that div to slide up from the bottom to a certain height. But if another link E.g. "Contact" is clicked, I want the contact div to slide up from the bottom and simultaneously the other div has to slide down. I have started learning jquery and hasn't got much knowledge.. However this is what i have tried.. But couldnt get the way it was intended.

The Div slides up on Click, but not sliding down when the other link is clicked. I require only the clicked div to be visible at a time and rest all the div has to either slide down or hide

```
<script>
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#ab').click (function() {
        $('#about').show().animate({marginTop:'-360px'});
    });
     $('#con').click (function() {
         $('#contact').show().animate({marginTop:'-360px'});

    });   
});
</script>
```

and here is the CSS

```css
#about {width:auto; background-color:#333333; height:360px; position:relative; display:none;}
#contact {width:auto; background-color:#FF3300; height:360px; position:relative; display:none;}
```

HTML goes here

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a id="ab" href="#">About </a></li> 
<li><a id="con" href="#">Contact</a></li> 

</ul>

<div class="maindiv">

<div id="about">About</div>
<div id="contact">Contact</div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: "couldnt get the way it was intended." Please be specific. What incorrect thing happens when you run your code?

Comment: The Div slides up on Click, but not sliding down when the other link is clicked. I require only the clicked div to be visible at a time and rest all the div has to either slide down or hide

Comment: Please post the HTML markup also..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#ab').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#contact').slideUp();
    $('#about').slideDown();
});
$('#con').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#about').slideUp();
    $('#contact').slideDown();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dBB3P/)

Comment: Palash, thanks for the suggestion. What if i have 6 links and 6 divs. Do i need to write for all. Or is there any other way to show only the clicked one and hide the rest